# Problem using multiple JOINs

Tags: mysql, join

I have a list of customer IDs in table `newsletter_subscriber`. I have an EAV table that contains a lot of information about these customers, table `customer_entity_varchar`.

For every entry in `newsletter_subscriber`, I'd like get a specific value from table `customer_entity_varchar` where the customer ID (named `entity_id` in this table) is the same as the `customer_id` in `newsletter_subscriber`, and the `attribute ID` is `1`.

Here's what I've tried

```
SELECT newsletter_subscriber.customer_id, customer_entity_varchar.value
FROM newsletter_subscriber
JOIN customer_entity_varchar
    ON newsletter_subscriber.customer_id = customer_entity_varchar.entity_id
    AND customer_entity_varchar.attribute_id = 1
```

This does not work, and `customer_entity_varchar.value` contains a wrong value, one that does not have an attribute ID of `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try both of this:

```
SELECT a.customer_id, b.value, b.attribute_id
FROM a
JOIN b
    ON a.customer_id = b.customer_id
WHERE b.attribute_id = 2
```

or:

```
SELECT a.customer_id, b.value, b.attribute_id
FROM a
JOIN (SELECT value, attribute_id FROM b WHERE attribute_id = 2) as b
    ON a.customer_id = b.customer_id
```

Comment: Both still return the same wrong value for "b.value" :(

Comment: OK so - give us "SHOW CREATE TABLE a\G (and for b) and give us some sample data (INSERT INTO a VALUES(.....)) (and for b). Give us the result you want and the logic you used to derive it.

Comment: Mh, without your data we won't be able to give you a correct example. I've tried it with my own demo data and I get the correct result. Maybe we misunderstand you.

Comment: I've updated the original question with my real data.

Comment: Actually, upon recreating the issue in another table with some sample data, I do get the expected result. It just doesn't work in my live data table. :/

Comment: Eh, turns out I had some errors in my sample data. Your solution is correct, thanks!

Comment: Hehe, just thought about it after reading your post a few minutes before. :-D Well nice that it helped you.